# Правильное отображение картинки заднего фона на разных экранах

Tags: android

День добрый.

Подскажите как сделать задний фон таким образом чтобы на разных экранах он не растягивался?
У меня чётко заданный дизайн и в центре круглый логотип. При просмотре на разных экранах он может быть кругом или овалом.

Речь идет не о ImageView, а именно layout background

Comment: фон картинкой идет или png например? так сложно ответить используя только предоставленную информацию

Answer (score 2):

Оберните ваш логотип в XML drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/circle">
</bitmap>
```

и уже этот ресурс ставьте как `background`